# Why am i getting garbage in for loop using string array, gets and puts?

Tags: c, for-loop, garbage, gets, puts

The puts function doesn't print the 3 strings as i input them. They contain garbage.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
    char para[20][3];
    int x;

    for(x=0; x<3; x++)
    {
      gets(para[x]);
      fflush(stdin);        
    }

    for(x=0; x<3; x++)
      puts(para[x]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try `char para[3][20];`

Comment: 1. `gets` doesn't exist anymore (since C11). 2. Assuming you have an ancient implementation where `gets` is available, you can't anymore than 2 chars because there's no space per call (that's the reason you should *never* use `gets`!).

Comment: What you need to do, is to take your source of learning (teacher or book) and then burn it with fire. Then get a better one.

Comment: @Adder, yes, but a 2D array contains the same number of chars right? so it shouldn't be an issue. True, the strings could be truncated, but garbage? no.

Comment: @Jean, input longer than 3 characters will overflow into the other strings. Moreover the strings would not contain a terminating zero at position 3

Comment: my point exactly. So mixed strings yes, garbage, no.

Comment: See [Why `gets()` is so dangerous it should **never** be used!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-dangerous-why-should-it-not-be-used)

Comment: See also [Using `fflush(stdin)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/)

Comment: @Adder it worked.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, Yes, it was mixed strings not garbage.

Comment: @PapoShow you don't need to confirm. _we know_ :)

Answer (score 2):

```
fflush(stdin);
```

is undefined behavior. It should be one output or update stream which is passed to `fflush`. This, what you have done might result in something weird to normal behavior.

`gets` is deprecated and not meant to be used. Use `fgets` instead. You should be able to enter `2` characters and a `\n` with the array size shown. Maybe you meant `para[3][20]`. `gets` has no safety over buffer overflow. That is there is `fgets` in the form of specifying the number of characters you want to read.